# Parse with Facebook Login: Server refused renewal request with error code: 190

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, parse-platform

I am working on an iOS App that uses Parse and Facebook.

For the Facebook login, I am following the guides on this page: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios

Following the guide, I have this code that validate the cached session:

```
// check if this cached session is still valid?
// does nothing if still valid
- (void) validateCachedSession
{
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            // handle successful response
            LogObvious(@"Facebook session validated. No problem");
        }
        else if ([error.userInfo[FBErrorParsedJSONResponseKey][@"body"][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"])
        {   // Since the request failed, we can check if it was due to an invalid session
            LogObvious(@"The facebook session was invalidated. Announce logged Out");

            // The persisted session is invalid. Logout!
            [self logout];
        }
        else
        {
            LogObvious(@"The facebook session was invalidated. Announce logged Out");

            // The persisted session is invalid. Logout!
            [self logout];
        }
    }];
}
```

As shown above, if the cached session is invalid, it should call logout:

```
- (void) logout
{
    [PFUser logOut];
    // Over here we will show the login button again.
}
```

In order to test this. I first logged into my app using a Facebook account. Then, I changed the password and revisit the app.

The app correctly recognises the session is invalidated and logout is called.

But when I click login again, the login function is returning this error:

```
Uh oh. An error occurred: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1e066140 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=1 "Server refused renewal request with error code: 190" UserInfo=0x1d56df10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Server refused renewal request with error code: 190}, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 190;
            "error_subcode" = 65001;
        };
    };
}}
```

WHY? Even if I terminate the app and restart it. The app will now stuck in this state - unable to login. Any help will be appreciated.

p/s: To be clear, this is my login function:

```
// to be called when user explicitly clicked a login button
- (void) loginByFacebookWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissionsArray
{
    LogFunctionCalledObvious();
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!user)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                [self logout];
            }
        } else if (user.isNew)
        {
            LogObvious(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
            [self requestLoggedInUserInfo];
        } else
        {
            LogObvious(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            [self requestLoggedInUserInfo];
        }
    }];
}
```

p/s2: OK, upon more investigation, so it stuck in this state until I go to the Settings->Facebook to reenter the new password. Is this the correct behaviour? shouldn't iOS6 promptly remind the user to change password when I changed the Facebook password from Facebook.com?

Comment: Somehow the Facebook app gets around this within context of app. It asks user to enter password again...you could possibly snoop what call they are making with Charles or some other packet sniffing for the re-auth call, I am very curious....The alternative is kinda bogus as many users have no idea what to do with that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error sub code points to this

```
static const int FBSDKSystemPasswordErrorSubcode = 65001;

case FBSDKSystemPasswordErrorSubcode:
            case FBAuthSubcodePasswordChanged:
                if (subcode == FBSDKSystemPasswordErrorSubcode
                    || [FBErrorUtility fberrorIsErrorFromSystemSession:error]) {
                    userMessageKey = @"FBE:PasswordChangedDevice";
                    userMessageDefault = @"Your Facebook password has changed. To confirm your password, open Settings > Facebook and tap your name.";
                    shouldNotifyUser = YES;
                } else {
                    userMessageKey = @"FBE:PasswordChanged";
                    userMessageDefault = @"Your Facebook password has changed. Please log into this app again to reconnect your Facebook account.";
                }
                break;
```

You will have to message the user somehow to do this

Your Facebook password has changed. To confirm your password, open Settings > Facebook and tap your name.

or

Your Facebook password has changed. Please log into this app again to reconnect your Facebook account.

Comment: I recently discovered that
NSString *message = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error] will instantly provide us a string that will describe the error.

Comment: Very helpful @mkto